# Looping through json array in JS

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON

```
[
 {
   "container":         
  [
    null,null,null,null,null
  ],

   "type":
  [
  "text","text","text","text","text"
  ],

   "role":
  [
    null,null,null,null,null
  ],

  "subtype":
  [
   null,null,null,null,null
  ],

  "maxlength":
  [
   null,null,ull,null,null

  ]

 }
]
```

My Code

```
for(i=0; i<jsonString.length; i++){
        container = jsonString[i];
        console.log(container);
        for(j in container){
            console.log(container[j]);
        }
    }
```

Thia isn't giving me the desired result. I know there a lot of these type of question, but I have applied several of them but to no avail.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you just trying to output the values of each item in the arrays?

Comment: @Jacques Yep...

Comment: @Jacques Can you help me here..?

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org) but an array with one object ([What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)). And `jsonString` is, if it contains the shown array, a really bad name as the content isn't a string...

Comment: _"Thia isn't giving me the desired result."_ And what _is_ the desired result?

Comment: @Andreas hey I this is json which I got after converting list into json using Gson..

Comment: The outer array only has a single element, an object. This object has keys.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, but you'd basically just need to loop through the array that `container[j]` is set to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....
If you just want to print the values of each level of the given format JSON.

```
 yourJSON.forEach(function(e)
    { 
      container = Object.keys(e)
      console.log(container)
      container.forEach(function(key){
        containerValue = e[key]
        console.log(containerValue)
        containerValue.forEach(function(value){
          console.log(value)
        })
      })
    })
```

Comment: thanks..but yourJSON.forEach is not a function error

Comment: yourJSON should be an array. I hope you are trying to iterate it on string so parse it first using JSON.parse(yourJSON) then iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need this instead:

```
var keys = Object.keys(jsonString[0]);
keys.forEach(key => {
  container = jsonString[0][key];
  console.log(container);
  container.forEach(j => {
    console.log(j);
  });
});
```

Edit:

Backwards compatible syntax:

```
var keys = Object.keys(jsonString[0]);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  container = jsonString[0][keys[i]];
  console.log(container);
  for (var j = 0; j < container.length; j++) {
    console.log(container[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks..but log showing error..that container.foreach is not a function

Comment: What environment are you using? Anyway, I added old-style JavaScript.